# Sync cloned carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 4 carousel that is placed inside the regular view. The user is able to view the carousel inside a modal.

The carousel in the modal and the carousel in the regular view need to be synced. So when one carousel slides, the other carousel slides as well.
I have tried to clone the original carousel and append it to the modal.

```
$(".carousel")
  .clone(true)
  .appendTo(".modal-body");
```

When I click on the slide buttons in the cloned carousel the original carousel slides but the cloned carousel stays on the original slide.

I have tried to use the [Bootstrap slide event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) to set the cloned slider active slide. This somehow gave a javascript syntax error: invalid regular expression.

How do I sync the cloned slider and slide both carousels at the same time?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gjk/pen/zEzeLz)

Comment: I think you'll have to do a deep clone of the object if you want to clone all of the event handlers etc, which I believe is `$(".carousel").clone(true, true).appendTo(".modal-body");` (note the second "true" in clone).

Comment: @delinear I have tried to add the second "true". Unfortunately, the cloned slider still only controls the original..

Comment: @Hi just check the response, regards ;).

Answer (score 0):

You have just to **rename** the ***id of your carousel*** and the **href** from the element html **A children** of you carousel.

```
(function($) {
  $("#carouselExampleIndicators1")
    .clone(true)
    .attr('id', 'carouselExampleIndicators2')
    .appendTo(".modal-body")
    .carousel()
    .children()
    .attr('href', '#carouselExampleIndicators2');
})(jQuery);
```

ex : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veZqGM

Comment: This does not solve the issue. If you click the original carousel's indicator, prev or next button, the cloned carousel should slide as well (even though it is not visible). AndIf you click the cloned slider indicator or prev / next button both sliders should slide as well.

Comment: @Gert-Jan Kooijmans i am no here to get a bounty or what else i just show you how to resolve your problem, on regards or your code posted i think the job is doing at 80%, have a nice day...